# Apache Kafka for .Net Clients Non-Confluent Packages

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

I currently want to be able to have my Kafka Clients written in .Net. Although Java/Scala tend to be the most popular methods of writing Kafka APIs, my company uses Cloudera for support for Apache Kafka which does not offer .Net Support. Confluent on the other hand does. I looked online and came across the Confluent Packages for .Net. Does anyone know how we can use Kafka APIs written in .Net without using Confluent? Thanks!

Comment: yep, take a look: https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net

Comment: You can use confluent-kafka-dotnet with Apache Kafka. What is the reason for not using it ?